# What's causing CPU utilization 100% during night time

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, virtual-machines, cpu-usage

I have a windows 2008 running virtual, and once in a while it says the CPU utilization reaches 100% during night, In the morning I only know that CPU utilization reached 100% but what not the reason behind it. Is there any way I can look at eventvwr logs and find out?

**Update:** Its a new box with a SQL server and some stupid antivirus running on that pc. I'm sure it is antivirus software, but want the proof.

Comment: What are you using to gauge the cpu utilization? If it's perfmon on the virtual, the issue may be on the host. What vm environment?

Comment: VMware, this is only happening on one PC, we have probably 100 pc's on VM. Is there a way I can review logs?

Comment: is it norton because norton runs a system idle scan that eats cpu up like crazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it: It's antivirus.. I kept watching the PC in VM ware and looked for CPU spike alerts, then logged on to PC and saw the antivirus utilizing 70% of CPU. we fixed it. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

What about SQL Server maintenance and backup plans? Maybe some are executing at night, and they have strong chances to fill all the resources available.

Windows defragmentation is another process which can take a large amount of CPU power. See defrag logs to figure out the last date it was running.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any scheduled backup jobs or something like it?

You can use Performance Counters functionality to collect info about workload for future analysis.

Comment: No, Its a new box with a SQL server and some stupid antivirus running on that pc. I'm sure it is antivirus software, but want the proof.

Comment: OMG, antivirus with SQL Server on same PC - it's highly explosive combination...

I think you should start from scheduleв tasks to find possible reason for scheduled antivirus scan or any other tasks with potentially high file activity (any kind of backup: e.g. SQL server backup, or any large number of files or huge files copying) - it cause high CPU load because of antivirus checking...
To avoid such checks exclude backup source/destination or any other suspicious locations from antivirus scan.

Or just completely disable scheduled Norton scan for one night. Is it so difficult?